# iOS app crashes on device not simulator: Im using an animation with 280+ images

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

ive read all the other similar questions/answers on this topic however im finding it hard to relate the answers to my problem. I have an animation of 280+ images that works(after a brief pause) on the emulator, and causes the iPad device crash all together (once I press the play button). Im guessing its a memory issue, is there a way to only load a certain amount of the animation at a time rather than all of it at once (maybe a possible solution.

Please see my code:

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i=2; i < 288; i++) {
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"invasive%04d.png", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    if (!image) {
        NSLog(@"Could not load: %@", name);
    }
    else {
        [array addObject:image];
    }
}

self.imageView.animationImages = array;
```

I've run 'Analyze' on my code and there are no issues.

Thanks all.

Comment: What is type is `self.imageView`? `UIImage` and what are your image sizes?   Remember that PNGs will de decompressed into RGBA 8:8:8:0 on loading.

Comment: @Marko - the images are quite big pixel wise, approx 1200 * 700.

Comment: Your code crashes on the device because you are using up all the memory by loading tons of images. It is a simple problem, but the solution is more complex than it seems. You would be better off doing some more research first to find an existing working solution instead of trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this feature was designed for such a task. Look at using a CADisplayLink and doing display updates there. Your primary app can keep the 10 images or so ahead of the display link, and the displayLink can release images as soon as they are done with. Look around you many find someone has posted code to do this already (using key of CADisplayLink)).

Answer (score 0):

when crash only device, I recommend crashlytics service for detecting crash.

http://www.crashlytics.com. is free.